# How to create sum function for all items in list using reduce and curry in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm playing with Scheme I want to run something like this:

```lisp
(reduce curry + '(1 2 3))
```

why this don't work? I also tried to run this:

```lisp
((curry + 1) 2)
((curry (curry + 1) 2) 3)
((curry (curry (curry + 1) 2) 3) 4)
```

In [LIPS my Scheme implementation](https://lips.js.org) it works (see [beta version REPL](https://lips.js.org/beta.html)). Why this don't work in Kawa or Guile. Is my implementation not correct? I don't have arity checks on function calls. The function is always called, is this the reason?

My curry function is written in JavaScript but I quickly tried to create function in Kawa to test this in implementation that probably much better then mine.

I use fold-right code from [SRFI-1 code on GitHub](https://github.com/scheme-requests-for-implementation/srfi-1/blob/master/srfi-1-reference.scm) after adding `check-arg` missing function.

And I used this curry version:

```lisp
(define curry (lambda (f arg1) (lambda (arg2) (f arg1 arg2))))
```

I think that for simple testing this should be fine.

One example that this should work is JavaScript:

```js
function type(label, arg, type) {
  // some type checking so you know which function
  // throw exception and why
  var arg_type;
  if (arg instanceof Array) {
     arg_type = 'array';
  } else if (arg === null) {
     arg_type = 'null';
  } else {
     arg_type = typeof arg;
  }
  if (arg_type !== type) {
    throw new Error(`${label}: Expecting ${type} got ${arg_type}`);
  }
}
function curry(fn, ...init_args) {
    type('curry', fn, 'function');
    var len = fn.length;
    return function() {
        var args = init_args.slice();
        function call(...more_args) {
            args = args.concat(more_args);
            //console.log({fn, len, args});
            if (args.length >= len) {
                return fn.apply(this, args);
            } else {
                return call;
            }
        }
        return call.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}


function add(...args) {
  return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log(curry(curry(curry(curry(add, 1), 2), 3), 4)());

console.log([1,2,3,4].reduce((a,b) => curry(a,b), add)());
```

The same code works in my LIPS:

```lisp
((--> #(1 2 3 4) (reduce (lambda (a b) (curry a b)) +)))
((--> #(1 2 3 4) (reduce (binary curry) +)))
```

**NOTE:** `-->` is macro that call reduce on array (vectors in Scheme are arrays and `-->` call method). lambda and binary function (inspired by Ramda library) is needed because Array::reduce add 3rd argument which is given array.

My question is why this don't work in Kawa, what I did wrong?

And I need to add that this:

```lisp
(reduce curry + '(1 2 3))
```

also don't work in LIPS and I'm not sure why, but I'm mainly asking about standard R7RS Scheme. I wanted to test in Standard Scheme to see if my implementation is correct.

**EDIT**: the simple implementation of curry was in fact wrong. Here is proper implementation:

```lisp
(define (curry f . args)
   (lambda more-args
      (apply f (append args more-args))))

((curry (curry (curry + 1) 2) 3) 4)
;; ==> 10
```

this is also simplified version the proper function, it should check length of the arguments before calling function, if it's less then original function it should keep returning lambda (not sure if you can check length of the parameters in Scheme). The above code works in Guile and Kawa.

So the other question (that remain) is how to make something like JavaScript reduce work in Scheme?

**EDIT2:** here is the function that works:

```
(define (fld fn init l)
  (do ((l l (cdr l))
       (result init (fn result (car l))))
    ((null? l) result)))


((fld curry + '(1 2 3 4)))
;; ==> 10
```

Tested in Kawa and Guile.

do you know any standard way to make something like fld in Scheme with default functions (without defining new functions, except `curry`)? For me this how reduce should work, this is how it works in JavaScript.

I've tried different combinations of fold and none of them works.

Comment: `(reduce curry + '(1 2 3))` is equivalent to `(fold curry 1 '(2 3))`.

Comment: @molbdnilo isn't + the first value that is used in calling reduce callback function,  `(lambda (acc item)` acc is + or result of curry and item is number? This is how it works in JavaScript. Is scheme version of reduce and fold different then in JS?

Comment: Yes, Scheme is different, and `reduce` only uses its second argument - which should be the right identity for the function - when the list is empty. (Also note that `(fold curry + '(2 3))` is `(curry 2 (curry 3 +))` ; it's a right fold.)

Comment: @molbdnilo do you know why `((curry (curry (curry + 1) 2) 3) 4)` don't work in Scheme? It works in my implementation. Do you know what is needed to make this work as in JavaScript? Do you know if there is function in SRF-1 that work like JavaScript reduce?

Comment: `curry` wants a binary function as its first argument, `(curry f x)` is a unary function. (Your definition of `curry` is odd; "currying" is a transformation of a function, not of a function and its first argument. Currying is not the same as partial application.)

Comment: @molbdnilo that's right instead of writing proper curry I taken one that I've found on SO. also curry usually accept default arguments when calling. After writing proper curry (same as my implementation it works). so the second question is how to make in Scheme something like JavaScript reduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @alinsoar I've found obsolete `fold-left` definition in [MIT Scheme docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/testing/mit-scheme-ref/Folding-of-Lists.html)

This code works in Kawa:

```lisp
(require 'list-lib) ;; import SFRI-1


;; this is equivalence of fold-left using fold from MIT Scheme docs
(define (fold-left proc knil list)
   (fold (lambda (acc elt) (proc elt acc)) knil list))


(define (curry f . args)
  "(curry f . args)

   simplified version of curry"
   (lambda more-args
      (apply f (append args more-args))))

(display ((fold-left curry + '(1 2 3 4))))
(newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with `mit-scheme` but I suspect in the other versions of scheme the [meaning of `reduce`](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/info/schemedocs/ref-manual/html/scheme_80.html) is identical.

```
(reduce curry '+ (list 1 2 3 4))
```

is equivalent to

```
(curry (curry 1 2) 3)
```

The definition of "standard" `reduce` says that `+` argument is used only if the list is empty.

So you need to redefine `reduce` such that to behave as you expect.

In mit-scheme you should use fold-left instead and also curry the `+` operator if you expect `+` to be all the time used.

*In the other versions of scheme* it works because `the + operator is also curried by default`.

This is because you defined curry so:

```
(define curry
  (lambda (f arg1)                           ;type 1
    (lambda (arg2)                           ;type 2
      (f arg1 arg2))))
```

Applying it recursively, you will apply `(curry (curry + 1) 2)`.  `(curry + 1)` **MUST** have the same type as `+` (i.e. `+` must have type 2).  I am working now and I do not have time to correctly define the curry for you now, but in the next days maybe I will find time.

NB: in a correct definition, you should expect that the output of `FOLD-LEFT` must be applied on the initial element (`0` for addition).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have correct version of curry written in JavaScript for my Scheme interpreter, do you know any standard way to make reduce or something else works as I expect (to fold the function with curry that actually work)?

Comment: @jcubic It is hard to see what happens.  I do not find a general solution.  You can try something like this, although it's not elegant. (((fold-left (lambda (op x)
                (let ((x0 (op x)))
                  (lambda (a)
                    (let ((a0 (x0 a)))
                      (lambda (b)
                        (+ a0 b))))))
              (lambda (x)
                (lambda (y)
                  (+ x y)))
              '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
   0)
  0).

Comment: I've looked at MIT Scheme docs and found obsolete function `fold-left` that give me exact results I want, there is even simple code show how implement that function using fold. see my answer.